# Images not showing on site - Even though they are there

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, images

I've got an issue that I really can't figure out. My site is [here](https://itjustgotpersonal.co.uk/) and as you can see two images from the top of the header are missing. The main image that isn't showing is [this one](https://itjustgotpersonal.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Wedding-Gifts.jpg)

If I open the image URL in firefox, then I see the image, if I open it in chrome I don't - I get a 404 error message from the server.

Even when I view the console log in firefox it says that the server return a 404 for the image, but shows it me if I go directly to the image URL.

Also in firefox, If I right click on an image, and click on "View image" it opens in a new window and shows perfectly.

Really confused with this one, here's what I've tried.

- Cleared all cache
- Turned off all cache plugins.
- Deleted my .htaccess
- Purged Redis cache
- Flushed DNS

I'm not sure what else I can do? I've also FTP'd to the site and I can see that the file do exist, and I can download them no issue.

I did change my Name servers 2 days ago, but propagation tests show everything is as it should be.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Have you by chance recently changed the URL of the website? If so you may need to do a permalink flush. Just so you're aware none of the images referenced in your question or linked are showing both return 404 errors, it could be that you are seeing the file locally because it is in your cache

Comment: Your website is currently down and now the image import is working fine on a live editor(It wasn't working before your website went down).

Comment: Looks like all is well now. You can answer your own question if you solved something. I saw the site was behaving the way you describe, then as I was writing a comment it went down, so I stopped writing. Now it is back up and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you might wanna check your error_log file in cPanel it will show you to the right direction  in terms of debugging.

What usually helps if you not that fair in development.
Go to your installed plugins and deactivate all of them, or
You might want to got to the cPanel and got to wp-content-> plugins and delete all of them manually.

if the images are showing then activate them 1 by 1 so you can see which one is causing this problem.

All the best.